# Rego to check if a map, contains a key that is defined in a separate list

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

Given a map, we would like to check if any of the keys in that map matches any item in a list.

In the case of kubernetes annotations being the "map":

```yaml
metadata:
  annotations:
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: something
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 60
```

Let's say that we want to trigger a violation if `external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl` is used. For that, we would add that item in a list of denied annotations. The value is not relevant.

```yaml
denied:
  - external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl
  - other-denied-annotation-1
  - other-denied-annotation-2
```

Violation should trigger if any of the denied annotations is present in the .metadata.annotations of the resource.

Although I searched and tried it, I was not able to. The already asked questions do not address this exactly and I was not able to make it work. We are using Gatekeeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd normally use a set for the "deny" list, and then simply check each annotation for membership:

```
package play

import future.keywords

denied_annotations := {
    "external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl",
    "other-denied-annotation-1",
    "other-denied-annotation-2",
}

deny[reason] {
    # iterate over all annotations in input
    input.review.object.metadata.annotations[key] 

    # for each key, check if it's present in deny list -
    # if using older OPA, you may need to use
    # `denied_annotations[key]` instead, which does the same
    key in denied_annotations       
    
    reason = sprintf("%s in denied annotations", [key])
}
```

Playground example [here](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/P0WwivOeAt).

Comment: That is awesome! Coincidentially, I JUST finished doing this https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/f4YwYmqNw7
Which is the best I was able to do based on previous pieces of code. Nontheless, your proposed answer is a lot more sound and elegant.

Comment: Using comprehensions. like you did, is key to many other Rego niceties, so probably a good lesson regardless. Some more here: https://github.com/StyraInc/rego-style-guide :)